# google maps triggers mouseout event before click on markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**UPDATE 1: it seems that the behavior described below is inconsistent and not always reproducible, even on the same browser**

**UPDATE 2: here's a screenshot of yet another behavior I came across**

The first `mouseover` is when the mouse first moves on the marker. Then a single click triggers in sequence `mouseout`, `mouseover` and finally `click`.

[image]

**Original question**

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API to render markers on a map, with which I'm trying to interact using the `mouseover`, `mouseout` and `click` events.

I would like to show an info window on `mouseover`, lock it open on `click` and close it on `mouseover` *unless* it's locked open.

The problem I'm seeing is that the `mouseout` event is always triggered before the `click` event, which results in a flickering of the info window, besides being conceptually wrong.

The snippet below contains a repro, without any info windows but simply logging the order in which the events are triggered.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="description" content="google maps marker events">
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #messages {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map
        });
        
        marker.addListener('mouseover',  e => append('mouse over'))
        marker.addListener('mouseout',  e => append('mouse out'))
        marker.addListener('click',  e => append('click'))
      }
      
      function append(text) {
        var div = document.createElement('div')
        
        div.textContent = text;
        
        document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(div)
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas if this is a bug in the Google Maps API library or if it's a known behavior, which possibly known workarounds?

Comment: What browser(s) do you see the issue in?  (I don't see it in Chrome).

Comment: I was seeing it in chrome, then just after writing the question I stopped seeing it. I'm fairly sure I saw it because I was seeing it in my app as well as in the repro that I wrote here, and then it disappeared. No clue really.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same probleme but i fixe it :lokk at my code i hope that hepl you friend .

```
 var prev_infowindow = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize(30.767172, -4.870733);
    ReadyAndRefresh();
});

function initialize(lat,long) {

    var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');
    var mapOptions = {
                //center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            zoom:z,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
           //  marker:true
        };
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
    if (data.TypeProjet==0 )
        var image = 'images/map-marker-green.png';
    if (data.TypeProjet == 1)
        var image = 'images/map-marker-blue.png';
    if (data.TypeProjet == 2)
        var image = 'images/map-marker-orange.png';
    if (data.TypeProjet == 5)
        var image = 'images/map-marker-dark.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title,
        icon: image
    });

    (function (marker, data) {
        var contentString = '<div id="information"  style="overflow: hidden;width :320px;" >' +
            '<div style="float :left;margin-right : 5px; ">';

       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content: contentString,

       });

        //Effect Click :
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function toggleBounce() {
           if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
               marker.setAnimation(null);
           } else {
               marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

               setTimeout(function () {
                   marker.setAnimation(null);
               }, 4200); // current maps duration of one bounce (v3.13)
           }
       });
        // Attaching a click event to the current marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) {
          //  infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
            if (prev_infowindow) {
                prev_infowindow.close();
            }
            prev_infowindow = infowindow;
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dblclick", function (e) {
            map.setZoom(16);
            //infoWindow.open(map, marker);

            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function (e) {
            if (prev_infowindow) {
                //prev_infowindow.close();
            }
        });
    })(marker, data);
}
```

Comment: By adding test for each action : google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function (e) {
            if (prev_infowindow) {
                //prev_infowindow.close();
            }
        });

Comment: this is not a solution, it's a workaround for your very specific case